# Replacing onClick() with addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html

Converting oclick() with addEventListener(), i have tried multiple times, But no Success. Can anyone help please. i have read in the book, that onlick() is not w3 standard, Any help will highly be aprreciated

Before with onclick() working Perfectly:

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Splitting number</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="" name="myForm">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Enter a phone number<br> [in the form (555) 555-5555]</td>
      <td><input name="input" type="text" size="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="Split" onclick="parseNumber()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Area code:</td>
      <td><input name="areaCode" type="text" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Number:</td>
      <td><input name="number" type="text" size="8"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript code:**

function parseNumber() {

```
var myForm = document.getElementById( "myForm" );

myForm.areaCode.value = "";

myForm.number.value = "";

var completeNumber = myForm.input.value.replace(/\s/g, '');

var areaCode = completeNumber.substr(1,3);

var tokens2 = completeNumber.substr(5).split( "-" );

myForm.areaCode.value = areaCode;

myForm.number.value = tokens2[0] + "-" + tokens2[1];

}
```

**after, Not working:**

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Splitting number</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Enter a phone number: in the form (555) 555-5555]
  <input name="input" type="text" size="40" id="number" ><br>
  <input type="button" value="Split" id="myBtn"><br><br>

  Area code: <input name="areaCode" type="text" size="5" id="areaCode"><br>

  Number: <input name="number" type="text" size="8" id="anotherNumber">
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript code**

```
var completeNumber = document.getElementById("number");
x = document.getElementById( "myBtn" );
function parseNumber() {


  x.addEventListener("click", parseNumber);
  completeNumber.replace(/\s/g, '');
  var areaCode = completeNumber.substr(1,3);

  var tokens2 = completeNumber.substr(5).split( "-" );

  document.getElementById("areaCode").innerHTML = areaCode.toString();

  document.getElementById("anotherNumber").innerHTML = tokens2[0].toString() + "-" + tokens2[1].toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this where `eventListener` is added outside the bounded function. Otherwise it will repeatedly bind an `eventListener` to the button.

Also place your `script.js` on the bottom of the `HTML` page. Because when the script executed the DOM element is not found since the DOM is not rendered at the script execution time.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Splitting number</title> 
</head>
<body>
Enter a phone number: in the form (555) 555-5555]
<input name="input" type="text" size="40" id="number" ><br>
<input type="button" value="Split" id="myBtn"><br><br>

Area code: <input name="areaCode" type="text" size="5" id="areaCode"><br>

Number: <input name="number" type="text" size="8" id="anotherNumber">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var completeNumber = document.getElementById("number");
var x = document.getElementById( "myBtn" );

function parseNumber() {

completeNumber.replace(/\s/g, '');
var areaCode = completeNumber.substr(1,3);

var tokens2 = completeNumber.substr(5).split( "-" );

document.getElementById("areaCode").innerHTML = areaCode.toString();

document.getElementById("anotherNumber").innerHTML = tokens2[0].toString() + "-" + tokens2[1].toString();

}

x.addEventListener("click", parseNumber);
```

Comment: Tried this one, no success 

Comment: @AbuzarManzoor Updated the answer. Have a look

Comment: like this
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>..??

Comment: @AbuzarManzoor: Please check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsachin/aeabwcy8/

Answer (score 2):

### You need to add the `event listener` outside the `function`.

The `listener` is listening (clues in the name) for a `mouse` `'click'` event on that element. When the event happens i.e you click on the element, it calls the `function` that it is assigned, in your case: `parseNumber`.

So since you are adding the event listener inside the `function`, it never gets added (as the `function` never gets called).

It should all work if you move the lines:

```
var x = document.getElementById( "myBtn" );
x.addEventListener("click", parseNumber);
```

outside the function. :)

Comment: @AbuzarManzoor you need to move the actual `x.addEventListener` line outside the function...

Comment: @Joe Iddon Don't forget he is assigning the `x` varaible inside the function as well, so he calls the event listener on an empty property.

Comment: @AbuzarManzoor also, its possible that you need to move the line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>` in the `html` to the bottom of the body as well. Because it may not be able to add the listener before the button is defined in the `html`. Not sure but maybe try that as well

Comment: @Fuross yes sorry, didn't see that :)

Answer (score 2):

I thnik no one actually read the question, if you already had a working example then changing `onclick` to `eventListener` is no problem:

```js
var parseNum = document.getElementById('parse-number');

function parseNumber() {

  var myForm = document.getElementById( "myForm" );

  myForm.areaCode.value = "";

  myForm.number.value = "";

  var completeNumber = myForm.input.value.replace(/\s/g, '');

  var areaCode = completeNumber.substr(1,3);

  var tokens2 = completeNumber.substr(5).split( "-" );

  myForm.areaCode.value = areaCode;

  myForm.number.value = tokens2[0] + "-" + tokens2[1];

}
    
parseNum.addEventListener("click", parseNumber);
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="" name="myForm">
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Enter a phone number<br> [in the form (555) 555-5555]</td>
    <td><input name="input" type="text" size="40"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Split" id="parse-number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Area code:</td>
    <td><input name="areaCode" type="text" size="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Number:</td>
    <td><input name="number" type="text" size="8"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```